# Come up with a method to find the smallest circle that covers two points with its center in x axis

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

Give two planar points `p1=(a1,b1)` and `p2=(a2,b2)` and a `line y=0`, design an algorithm to find the smallest circle that covers both points such that its center `(x, 0)` lies on `y=0`. There is no time or space requirement.

Although this problem seems simple, but I think it's kinda tricky to solve. Could you give some help? Thanks!

Comment: Can you remove the unicode characters? They are making the post slightly unreadable and less understandabale.

Comment: does "cover" mean 1) the circle contains the two points, e.g. both points lie on the circumfence or 2) the "filled" circle contains both points?

Comment: The problem means those two points don't all have to be on the circumference. So it means the second one.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both points should lie on the circumfence of the circle:

- find midpoint of [p1, p2]: midpoint := ((a1+a2)/2, (b1+b2)/2))
- find line perpendicular to [p1, p2] in midpoint
- find intersection of this line with x axis
- this intersection is the midpoint of your circle

**Edit**

If both points should be part of the "filled" circle:

Find the x values of both points: a1, b1

If the center (found above) is within [(a1,0), (b1,0)] then you have the smallest circle

if the center found above is < a1 then move it to (a1,0)

if the center is > b1 then move it to (b1,0)

Comment: But I think this problem means those two points don't all have to be on the circumference. So there might be other better answer than this one.